# How do I access the DOM element of another component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

My app is structured like this:

```
<nav></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

In the router-outlet I have different components based on the route. In a few of those pages I need to access the DOM elements of either the nav or the footer for things like pageYOffset, height and etc. for sticky positioning. I know of things like ViewChild, Renderer2 and ElementRef but not really sure how it would work. Do I create a service? What might that look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the child components are of type `NavComponent` and `FooterComponent`, you can retrieve the corresponding DOM elements with `@ViewChild(..., { read: ElementRef })` in `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
@ViewChild(NavComponent, { read: ElementRef }) private navElementRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(FooterComponent, { read: ElementRef }) private footerElementRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const navElement = this.navElementRef.nativeElement;
  const footerElement = this.footerElementRef.nativeElement;
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehuor4) for a demo.

---

These elements can be made accessible to other parts of the application with a simple service:

```
export class AppElementsService {
  public navElement: HTMLElement;
  public footerElement: HTMLElement;
}
```

and set in the application component:

```
@ViewChild(NavComponent, { read: ElementRef }) private navElementRef: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(FooterComponent, { read: ElementRef }) private footerElementRef: ElementRef;

constructor(private appElementsService: AppElementService) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.appElementsService.navElement = this.navElementRef.nativeElement;
  this.appElementsService.footerElement = this.footerElementRef.nativeElement;
}
```

---

Note: you may need to set the `display` style attribute of the `nav` and `footer` components to `block` or `inline-block` in order to get the position and size of the corresponding elements.